# How do I move stuff?

Tags: dream-house-days

I want to place a piece of furniture but there is another piece of furniture in the way. I can't seem to find an option to move or remove. Is there something there that I am missing, or did I nail this thing to the floor forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options available if you want to move something:

- The Remove option, under Install, to destroy the item, and then place it down in the new location.
- The Rearrange option, which is directly underneath the Remove option.  You can freely move items from one apartment to another without a problem, but it will still cost you half of the original building cost to do so.

Obviously, Rearrange is cheaper than Remove and rebuilding, so I'd recommend that option.